# How to get a particular field from ls output

Tags: shell

i am trying to get the info of the latest folder created in a particular path.
Here i am using the below command to fetch and filter the results so that i get only folders starting with 11,12,19:

```
ls_info=$(ls -lrt /orcl/grid/product |grep '11\|12\|19')
```

The output of ls_info is :

```
total 12
drwxrwx--- 3 oragrid oinstall 4096 May 21  2014 11.2.0.3
drwxr-xr-x 3 oragrid oinstall 4096 Feb 25  2019 11.2.0.4
```

How can i fetch "11.2.0.4" from this,which is the latest created folder.
Please suggest.Thanks.

Comment: If a file is created in `2011` or was creates at 19'th of May, do you want it in the output too? `i get only folders starting with 11,12,19` that's not what grep does..

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Do not parse `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead). Use `find` instead. First get the list of directories you want and print the directories with the modification timestamps. Then sort the list, filter newest line and remove the timestamp. With GNU utilities you can:

```
find /orcl/grid/product -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d '(' -name '11*' -o -name '12*' -o -name '19*' ')' -printf "%Ts\t%f\n" | sort -n | cut -f2- | tail -n1
```

Comment: how can i assign this to a variable?

Comment: Thank you ..This is very helpful for beginner like me